# How do I add an onPaste listener to a summernote in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, summernote

A `summernote` is dynamically added to my site. It means that after user has clicked a button, it will pop up a window with a `summernote div`.

And I **would** like to add an onPaste listener for that `div` using AngularJS.

I **don't** want to use jQuery to add the listener like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        onPaste: function(e){
            setTimeout(function (e) {
                alert('pasted');
            }, 20);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a directive for this: [here](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote)

Just inject the dependency in your module like this: `angular.module('myApp', ['summernote']);` and you can use it as an [element](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote#as-element): `<summernote></summernote>` or an [attribute](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote#summernote-directive): `<div summernote></div>`

[Here](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote#event-listeners) is a link to the event listeners, including paste.

**EDIT**

In order to wire up the paste event handler, you need to add `on-paste=paste()` to the directive as an attribute and add the corresponding "paste" function to your $scope inside your controller. Here is the complete example listed in the docs:

```
function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() { console.log('Summernote is launched'); }
  $scope.enter = function() { console.log('Enter/Return key pressed'); }
  $scope.focus = function(e) { console.log('Editable area is focused'); }
  $scope.blur = function(e) { console.log('Editable area loses focus'); }
  $scope.paste = function(e) { console.log('Called event paste'); }
  $scope.change = function(contents) {
    console.log('contents are changed:', contents, $scope.editable);
  };
  $scope.keyup = function(e) { console.log('Key is released:', e.keyCode); }
  $scope.keydown = function(e) { console.log('Key is pressed:', e.keyCode); }
  $scope.imageUpload = function(files) {
    console.log('image upload:', files);
    console.log('image upload\'s editable:', $scope.editable);
  }
}
```

And in your markup:

```
  <summernote on-init="init()" on-enter="enter()" on-focus="focus(evt)"
        on-blur="blur(evt)" on-paste="paste()" on-keyup="keyup(evt)"
        on-keydown="keydown(evt)" on-change="change(contents)"
        on-image-upload="imageUpload(files)" editable="editable" 
        editor="editor">
    </summernote>
```

Comment: But I wouldn't set `on-paste` for every `summernote div`.. How could I set an `on-paste` listener for every `summenote div`?

Comment: They said that we can use `function DemoController($scope) {$scope.paste = function(e) { console.log('Called event paste'); }}` to add a listener, and call it in `on-paste`. But where should I add this function?

Comment: So, in AngularJS, it should be `angular.module('xxxx',['summernote']).controller('PageController', function($scope){$scope.paste=function(e){/* Things to add */})`??

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to add the directive to your markup. Obviously, you'll also need to install the summernote directive (there are directions on the site I linked to).